# C# Custom datatype with "choices"

Tags: c#, oop, types

I need a custom datatype for order status, how can this be done in C#? Below is an example of what I mean.

Order can be in 4 states:
- In queue
- Handling
- Shipping
- Received

```
class Order {
    public OrderStatus status { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
Order myorder = new Order();
myorder.status = OrderStatus.queue;

...

if (myorder.status == OrderStatus.received) 
{
    ...
}
```

How to define the OrderStatus class so it has those four options to select from?

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean an enum? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: Why not create a struct or another class?

Comment: Enums is the answer, doh

Comment: You are looking for an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum OrderStatus {
    InQueue,
    Handling,
    Shipping,
    Received
}
```

- You may or may not need to mark it public depending on your needs
- You may or may not need to set specific integer values to each of the enum items. Once you start persisting them you never (well, would be easier not to) want to change the order. By assigning specific values can allow you to re-order and group them in ways that might make sense etc...

As an Example:

```
enum OrderStatus {
    NewOrder = 1,

    OnHold = 6,
    CancelledOrder = 9,

    // Approval States
    WaitingApproval = 7,
    ApprovalRejected = 8,

    // Processing
    InQueue = 2,
    Handling = 3,

    // We've done our job!
    Shipping = 4,
    Received = 5
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an enumeration, which is a "collection of possible values"

```
public enum OrderStatus
{
    InQueue,
    Handling,
    Shipping,
    Received
}
```

A variable of that type would be used like:

```
public OrderStatus myStatus;
myStatus = OrderStatus.Shipping;

if (myStatus == OrderStatus.Shipping)
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare enumeration:

```
public enum OrderStatus
{
    InQueue,
    Handling,
    Shipping,
    Received 
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) you can read more.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar than you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Enum for that:

```
public enum Orderstatus{ 
    InQueue, 
    Handling, 
    Shipping, 
    Received 
}
```